# Install gitlab library to docker-compose based interpreter environment in PyCharm project

Tags: git, docker-compose, pip, pycharm, gitlab

I need to install one package to the docker-compose based environment of the application.
The package is not downloaded on pip, therefore, I install it via GitLab URL. I can successfully install it on venvs I created for test the package, but when I try to install it on the docker-compose app I start to get mistakes.
That's how it looks in the requirments.txt file:

```
git+https://git.somerepo.com/smth/smth/package-name.git#egg=package_name
```

When I try to install I receive an error message:

```
Running command git clone -q +https://git.somerepo.com/smth/smth/package-name.git /tmp/pip-install-kqlwiux8/package-name_2ba6c558a2e14343acef3f3e34d49f18
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.somerepo.com': No such device or address
```

If i change the requirement to git@git.somerepo.com/smth/smth/package-name.git#egg=package_name  it doesn't recognized as a requirement.

When I try to install it from the terminal with the command:

```
docker-compose --project-name=some_backend_api -f docker/dev/docker-compose.yml run core /bin/bash -c 'pip install git+https://git.somerepo.com/smth/smth/package-name.git#egg=package_name'
```

I receive the result that the package is successfully installed:

```
Successfully built package-name
Installing collected packages: pandas, package-name
Successfully installed pandas-1.3.4 package-name-0.1.0
```

But when i check pip list:

`docker-compose --project-name=some_backend_api -f docker/dev/docker-compose.yml run core /bin/bash -c 'pip list`

I couldn't find the package-name and couldn't access it
When I rebuild the containers, I once again encounter the git fatal error. What might be the reason for this git fatal error, and why I couldn't find the package inside the pip list, after successfully installing it via terminal?

[Warning after install-requirements command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trA8y.png)
[errors after running the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr8HN.png)

Comment: Switch to ssh-based cloning - `git+ssh` instead of `git+https` in the requirements. git is trying to ask for authentication parameters interactively, which can't work during docker build because it doesn't have a TTY to offer.

Comment: SSH with keypaors or non-interactive HTTPS auth.